# Can't log into GCE instance, Serial Console shows awaiting input

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I rebooted my instance and noticed on the serial console the following message.

```
[....] Starting web server: apache2Apache/2.2.22 mod_ssl/2.2.22 (Pass Phrase Dialog)
Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
Server [serverdomain].com:443 (RSA)
Enter pass phrase:
```

however when trying to log in via terminal using the appropriate gcutil string

I get the following

```
INFO: Running command line: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/kunalpatel/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 kunalpatel@[server IP address] --

ssh: connect to host [server ip address] port 22: Connection refused
```

So it seems I'm locked out of my machine... unless somehow the passphrase was passed through and allowing connections to the server again.

Have you run into this or know of an alternative way to connect?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are both great general debugging advice, but based on the console log, it seems that your instance is configured to ask you for an SSL passphrase on the serial console to unlock your private key.  Unfortunately, Compute Engine doesn't currently provide a way to send data to the serial console.

To resolve this, you'll need to reconfigure apache to not encrypt the key on disk.  That way, it won't interrupt the boot process with a prompt on an unresponsive channel.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a firewall rule configured for port 22 under your network.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't delete you firewall rule for shh into your machines.

If you're able to login into other VM, but not this one, you can reboot your VM from your Developers Console.

Mary